# Анимация загрузки

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar

Использую этот код для загрузки файлов. Проблема в том, что анимация загрузки в `progrssView` осуществляется в последний момент. А не в течение всего процесса. Как решить проблему?

Использую NSURLSession как советовали в предыдущем вопросе

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
_progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
    _progressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255 green:0.0/255 blue:0.0/255 alpha:0.4];
    [[_progressView layer]setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 150, 100, 25)];
    [[_progressView layer]setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    _progressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [_progressView setProgress:(float)(50/100) animated:YES];

    [[_progressView layer]setCornerRadius:_progressView.frame.size.width / 8];
    [[_progressView layer]setBorderWidth:1];
    [[_progressView layer]setMasksToBounds:TRUE];
    _progressView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:_progressView];

    _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    [self.progressView setProgress:0 animated:NO];
 }
```

Comment: убедитесь, что setProgress вызывается на main thread. И возможно ваши данные просто приходят за один раз (если их тем немного)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй обновить прогресс так:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //update UI in main thread.
            [self.progressView setProgress:totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite animated:YES];
        });  }
```

И действительно добавь лог, чтоб посмотреть как часто тебе приходят данные, как советовали сверху.

Comment: Попробовал. Не работает. Если скачиваю 50мб сразу видно что анимация идет с задержкой

Comment: странно. А ты не пробовал выводить прогресс в label, например?
Также попробуй вызывать dispatch_async в блоке 
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //NSLog(@"parameter1: %d parameter2: %f", parameter1, parameter2);
dispatch_async + updateUI
});

Comment: не работает обновление label?

Comment: В  label прогресс выводить не пробовал. Как это нужно сделать в моем случае?

Comment: Просто выведи количество байт в лейбле - label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", totalBytesWritten];
Примерно так.

Comment: Вывел. Цифры увеличивается . Потом они останавливаются. И после остановки идет анимация

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42882/discussion-between--and-user).